# Get environment variables in a cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables, python-3.8

I have a Cloud Function in GCP that queries BigQuery in a specific project/environment. As I have multiple environments I would like to get the current project/environment of the cloud function. This is so that I can access BigQuery in the corresponding environment. Of course I could just hardcode the project_id, but I would like to do this programmatically.

According to [Google](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#functions_env_var_access-python) environment variables are set automatically. But when I try to access those I cannot find any of them.

For instance I have tried the following, which gives me none of the env. var listed by Google.

```
print(os.environ)
```

Anyone managed to access environment variables at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those environment variables you are referring to only applies to python 3.7, the second section on that page (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes) states :

> All languages and runtimes other than those mentioned in the previous section will use this more limited set of predefined environment variables.

This means the GCP_PROJECT is no longer set with 3.8 (at least for now).

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3.8 there is a workaround:

```
import google.auth

_, project_id = google.auth.default()
print(project_id)
```

Comment: This is the answer for python38 and python39. Kudos @redmode!

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine

```
import os
os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT')
```

Comment: Not working for me. When running print(os.environ) I do not get any of the environment variables that are set automatically by GCP. Are you running python 3.8?

I had to move from 3.7 to 3.8 due to this issue: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215191

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to return from `get_env`?

```py
def get_env():
    print(os.environ)
    if 'GCP_PROJECT' in os.environ:
       return os.environ['GCP_PROJECT']
```

That can probably be simplified to just the following line:

```py
environment = os.environ.get('GCP_PROJECT')
```

Comment: Problem is that print(os.environ) only gives me local env var. Not the environment variables that are set automatically when you deploy your function to the GCP environment.

Comment: Are you talking about locally, or when deployed?

Comment: When deployed, I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the `os.environ.get()` to

```py
from os import environ

db_user = environ["DB_USER"]
db_pass = environ["DB_PASS"]
db_name = environ["DB_NAME"]
db_host = environ["DB_HOST"]
db_port = environ["DB_PORT"] # if not used, default 3306 anyway
```

or use the even shorter

```py
from os import getenv

db_user = getenv("DB_USER")
...
```

You have to add the variables during the first step of the edit (your value at the right side that is cut here):

[image]